# A query I ran yesterday isn't in the plan cache, but older and newer ones are. Why?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019, plan-cache

Yesterday, I ran a big ad-hoc query that I didn't save. Today, I want to see it again. I thought that I'd hunt through the plan cache. To my surprise, I can find older queries and newer queries, but not the one that I ran. Why might this be?

I know that I should have Query Store turned on, but I haven't done it yet.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I presume that the plan was large, and presented the most space if deleted, and the others' value was lower to delete hence kept instead. Older might still be referenced frequently... Newer ones probably replaced others, those deleted were chosen for the benefit / cost to recreate equivalency...

Answer (score 8):

From [Plan Cache Internals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/tn-archive/cc293624(v=technet.10)):

> Determining which plans to evict is based on the cost of the plan, which will be discussed in the next section. When eviction starts is based on memory pressure. When SQL Server detects memory pressure, zero-cost plans will be removed from cache and the cost of all other plans is reduced by half.

And later:

> Evicting plans from cache is based on their cost. For adhoc plans, the
> cost is considered to be zero, but it is increased by one every time
> the plan is reused. For other types of plans, the cost is a measure of
> the resources required to produce the plan.

The second sentence here likely answers why your single-use adhoc query plan disappeared, while others did not.